# Jade path resolution for expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, web, pug

Background info:  I am working on a web app for express. Currently, I have all views in one directory. I would like to structure my views folder to contain multiple directories to group views together. The problem is that when I do that my paths get messed up. For example, if I have a dir structure like:

```
views
->photos
-->search.jade
-->stats.jade
layout.jade
```

and if I click the stats link first, then search link, I will get an error saying that it could not find 'photos/photos/search'. I think it has something to do with the fact that I loaded stats from the photos directory and it somehow tacks on the extra photos to the dir path since the hrefs are relative I think. I read around in the API docs and online with no information. Can someone shed some light on this?

Inside my stats or search files would contain `extends ../layout`. Here is what my layout.jade looks like.

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
    block header
  body
    // Navigation
    nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top(role='navigation')
      .container
        // Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display
        .navbar-header
          button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='socialid-nav')
            span.sr-only Toggle navigation
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
          a.navbar-brand(href='#') HOME
        // Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling
        .collapse.navbar-collapse(id='app-nav')
          ul.nav.navbar-nav
            li
              a(href='/home') Home
            if user
                li
                  a(href='photos/search') Search
                li
                  a(href='photos/stats') Stats
                li
                  a(href='/logs') Search Logs
                li
                  a(href='#') Logged in as: #{user.username}(#{userRole})            
                li
                  a(href='/signout') Sign Out
        // /.navbar-collapse
      // /.container
    // Page Content
    block content

    // Footer
    footer
      .row
        .col-lg-12
          p Copyright © SOCIAL-ID 2014

    block scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally found the most simplest of fixes to this and it turns out it was just a typo.  I changed the code to look like:

```
li
  a(href='/photos/search') Search
li
  a(href='/photos/stats') Stats
```

I guess the missing '/' character at the beginning of the href path told the browser to look relative to the current static file directory. Adding it tells the browser to look relative to public directory.